# Right-click on taskbar's icon and slabs in start will not open context menu on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, windows-10-upgrade, right-click

I just upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and found out that when I right-click icons on taskbar for unpin them nothing happened after click. I though it was just delay so I waited few minutes and still nothing. Then I found out that it even does not work in starmenu when I wanted to unpin "store","xbox", etc. slabs. So I opened the Task manager and found window explorer and simply restarted it. After that I was able to right-click my installed icons (Chrome, Steam) pinned to taskbar. But when I right-clicked on "Microsoft Edge" nothing happened and then I couldnt open "right-click menu" on anything. So I restarted winexplorer from task manager again and tried unpin slabs in startmenu and again...my installed apps were possible to upin (because I opened "right-click menu" on them) but microsoft's slabs bugged "right-click popup menu" again. Where is the problem ? I can not find solution anywhere on the internet. Please help, this problem drives me crazy. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by deleting some referenced Context Menu Registry keys that seemed to no longer exist.

1. Start **regedit**
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DIRECTORY\SHELLEX\CONTEXTMNUHANDLERS`
3. There were two folders there that showed up as a GUID instead of a name. Deleted them.

This fixed the issue on both my private desktop and on my work PC.

Comment: I've tried this without any luck :(

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but I'll leave this solution for others. After seeing Ferry's post referring to context menu registry keys, I decided to try running CCleaner (https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) as it flushes the Windows explorer recent location links in right click menus. Make sure you have all the options under "Windows Explorer" in the cleaner checked. This seemed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: I've tried this to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

When a variety of other solutions did not work, [Fix the right-click Context Menu on the Start Menu and Taskbar through PowerShell](https://www.itechtics.com/fix-right-click-not-working/#Fix_the_right-click_Context_Menu_on_the_Start_Menu_and_Taskbar_through_PowerShell) once fixed broken right-click context menus in a ***Windows 10 Home** Version **21H1** OS build **19043.1083** Experience **Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0*** task bar.

This solution calls for running PowerShell as Administrator, and then running the following command:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

The command runs for quite a long time and error messages may be ignored.

After following these instructions, right-click context menus in the task bar started working again (reboot not needed).