# Right clicking on windows 10 does nothing

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, start-menu

I am having similar issues to what others had. I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, and all went fine and smooth except for not being able to right-click **some** shortcuts in start menu or taskbar.

For instance, right-clicking the Word 2013 icon does nothing (Thanks to my firewall I noticed that it launches the Windows Problem Reporting thing in the background). Clicking to expand the jump list also does the same. Right clicking Word's icon in the task bar also does this.

This occurs with various applications (e.g. Word, Excel, Powerpoint, Mathematica, etc).

[image]

I have already tried:

1. [Both answers in here](https://superuser.com/questions/947789/cant-right-click-on-windows-10-taskbar-icons)
2. [Both answers here](https://superuser.com/questions/951306/right-click-on-taskbars-icon-and-slabs-in-start-will-not-open-context-menu-on-w)
3. I've also included disabling all non-Windows context-menu options and restarting explorer.exe, but to no avail

Comment: Microsoft has a Start menu troubleshooter diagnostic pack which runs 4-5 checks and determines the problem. It can be downloaded from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12385/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-opening-start-menu-cortana).

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it found no errors... I was thinking this would be some context-menu problem, but I could not solve it by disabling all non-Microsoft context menu options.

Comment: There is a comprehensive fix here that you may try. http://www.urtech.ca/2015/09/solved-fix-windows-10-start-button-does-nothing-in-10-minutes/ Completely resets Start layout to defaults. If that doesn't help, creating a new user account may be the solution.

Comment: The problem is not on the Start button per se, it's on specific applications. For instance, I can customize the start button, just not some specific windows there or at the taskbar.